# Avoiding overwriting a pygame surface when using .blit

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface

I am attempting to clear a surface before using `blit()` to another surface. Before I was clearing path_surface by making it opaque, using blit() to the movement_surface, and resetting it's opacity [(more on that here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77812711/unable-to-undraw-on-a-transparent-surface-in-pygame/77812751#77812751).

The issue I'm now having is that it is overwriting everything on the `movement_surface`, so instead I need to just clear the `path_surface` before I blit it to `movement_surface`. In an attemp to do this I'm creating a `clear_surface` and trying to use it to reset `path_surface`. It does not have any effect.

Code:

```
def undraw_movement(self):
    empty = pg.Color(0,0,0,0)
    clear_surface = pg.Surface(self.path_surface.get_size(), pg.SRCALPHA)
    clear_surface.set_alpha(150)
    clear_surface.fill(empty)
    clear_surface.set_alpha(None)

    self.path_surface.blit(clear_surface, (0,0))
    self.movement_surface.blit(self.path_surface, (0,0))
```

Comment: There is no good solution to your problem. Why are you trying to remove everything in this complicated way? It is common to draw everything anew in every frame. If you are trying to achieve a better performance, you have to keep in mind that such a complicated clearing algorithm is actually much slower than redrawing everything. See also  [How to clean up sprites without covering other things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73342080/how-to-clean-up-sprites-without-covering-other-things/73342167#73342167)

Comment: Redrawing everything is expensive because I'm using a large board made of hexagons and each time I have to calculate the vertices of the hexagons before drawing them and it takes a while. I maybe look into just caching the drawn image for each tile if what I'm trying to achieve here is impossible.

Comment: Almost every game redraws everything in every frame. And the positions of the hexagons should be stored somewhere so that they don't have to be recalculated again and again. Anyway, I suspect that your "clear" algorithm is much more time consuming than recalculating the positions.

Comment: That make sense, I seem to have been going about this problem from the wrong end. I'll rework how I'm drawing my grid so that I can redraw every frame without performance issues. This will definitely make it easier to update, haha. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to "undo" a blit in pygame, and unfortunately without the full code or an example of what you want to happen it is not possible to find a simpler way. If you only want to remove the latest move you could keep a copy of the surface with [surface].copy() before making any changes to it and return to that when needed. If you really need to be able to remove any move the only thing I can think of would be creating a new surface for every move that is made and assigning it a position, then when you need to remove the move you can just take that surface out of the list and reblit everything.

Without the full code or knowing what you are trying to achieve on a larger scale I can't really offer any help other than this. If you are struggling preformancewise from drawing there are other solutions, such as using colorkey instead of SRCALPHA if you don't need a transparency value or only drawing 60 times per second that are much simpler to implement and cleaner solutions in general.